# What is the limit of modulo (number base) that starts immutable result for multiplied n-digit numbers?

Tags: number-theory

For a starter my apologies for a question that I couldn't express better, because it is a the most recent target of my wonder. I'm not even sure if my initial calculations are correct, but it seems that if I choose to multiply for example 216*216 in base 10, result is [4, 6, 6, 5, 6]. If I increase the base of the number I will get up to base 37, when the result for multiplying $216_{37}*216_{37}$ is $[4, 4, 25, 12, 36]$.

But now if I increase the base, result won't change after the base 37. What is the explanation for this, or even more importantly, is my objection right at all?

I found this when implementing a simple place-value based multiplication algorithm.

Comment: Corrected the base 37 result digit order to make both series consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well $(2x^2+x+6)^2=4x^4+4x^3+25x^2+12x+36$ and as soon as you put $x\gt 36$ you get no carries from the coefficients.

---

For an arbitrary base $n$ the symbol $[a_r, a_{r-1} \dots a_0]$ means the number $a_r n^r+a_{r-1}n^{r-1}+\dots +a_0$ and we can set $p(x)=a_r x^r+a_{r-1}x^{r-1}+\dots +x_0$. The coefficients here are all non-negative.

Suppose $q(x)$ is another polynomial with non-negative coefficients and that the coefficients of $p(x)q(x)$ are $b_s, b_{s-1}, \dots b_0$.

If we have that $0\le b_j\lt n$ for $0\le j\le s$ then the corresponding symbol made out of the coefficients will be a valid symbol modulo $n$. For any polynomial with non-negative integer coefficients this happens whenever $n$ is greater than the largest coefficient.

Comment: Seems reasonable. Is there a general approach to this? To find out the forementioned $x$ for any two multiplied integers?

Comment: @MarkokraM I've added something to my answer, but essentially each integer in the symbol for a number is a coefficient of a power of the base.

Comment: So is it that the digits in the first place, here 6*6 + 1, multiplied plus one is the max modulo?

Comment: It looks like no, because for 999*999 the limit of the modulo would be 244...

Comment: @MarkokraM For $999^2$ indeed you have $(9x^2+9x+9)^2=81(x^4+2x^3+3x^2+2x+1)$ and the highest coefficient is $3\times 81=243$.

Comment: Now I got it, the highest coefficient of the polynomial + 1 is the modulo I'm looging for. Thanks for clarifications and addition to the answer.